# how do i print a string array at array index?

Tags: java, arrays

Having trouble getting my program to output the index[1] of my array "nArray", if nArray[0] = bob, and nArray[1] = jim. When I'm trying to print the input, it will print nArray[0] bob, but when it gets to nArray[1] it does not output.

```
public String toString(){
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}

public static double salePercent(double[] sArray, String[] nArray){
    double total = 0;        
    for (int b =0 ; b < sArray.length; b++){ // sum calculator

        total = total + sArray[b];
    }

    double percent = 0;        
    for (int k = 0; k < nArray.length; k++){

        System.out.println(nArray[k]);

    }

     return total;
}
```

edit 
 showing how i am creating and declaring and creating my arrays 
in my mainclass

```
System.out.println("How Many Employees :");
    int size = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine(); //dummy


    String[] nArray = new String[size]; // array for staff names
    double[] sArray = new double[size]; // array for staff sales

    for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
     sales.nameArray(nArray,i, input); 

     input.nextLine();


     sales.saleArray(sArray,i,input);
     }
     sales.salePercent(sArray, nArray);
```

in my class
          public String inputStaff(){

```
      Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
      int size;
      System.out.print("How Many Employees :\n");
      size = user.nextInt();

      user.nextLine(); //dummy to grab \n value from nextInt so nextline can function


      String[] nArray =new String[size];
      double[] dArray = new double[size];
      int i =0;

      for(i = 0 ; i < nArray.length;i++){

        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        nArray[i] = user.nextLine(); 

        System.out.print("Enter sales ($): ");
        dArray[i] = user.nextDouble();
        user.nextLine();


  }
    return null;    
  }

   public static String[] nameArray(String[] nArray,int i,Scanner input){

        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        nArray[i] = input.nextLine(); 


    return nArray;
}

public static double[] saleArray(double[] sArray,int i,Scanner input){

    System.out.print("Enter sales ($): ");
    sArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
    return sArray;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: Can you show your input as well? The code snippet seems to be right, there must some problem how you pass the input

Comment: Additionally, you can debug this kind of problem yourself. Check the length of nArray before the loop block, see if the length is really 2

Comment: Can you show us the code where you calling that method?

Comment: If you're going to override `toString()`, why re-implement the behavior from `Object`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch lol I just noticed.